# Relabel PROC FREQ tables data labels in SAS

Tags: sas, frequency, proc

I have data that is numerical or was numerical and I converted to be a numeric label but am doing Chi Square test and my data categories actually have character labels.  I would like to change the numbers highlighted in screenshot to character descriptors.  How do I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
IF NUMOFRACES GT 1 THEN RACE=1;
ELSE IF H1GI4=1 THEN RACE=2;
ELSE IF H1GI6A=1 THEN RACE=3;
ELSE IF H1GI6B=1 THEN RACE=4;
ELSE IF H1GI6C=1 THEN RACE=5;
ELSE IF H1GI6D=1 THEN RACE=6;
ELSE IF H1GI6E=1 THEN RACE=7;

IF H1PF28=1 THEN SPEEDOFREC=1;
ELSE IF H1PF28=2 THEN SPEEDOFREC=2;
ELSE IF H1PF28=3 THEN SPEEDOFREC=3;
ELSE IF H1PF28=4 THEN SPEEDOFREC=4;
ELSE IF H1PF28=5 THEN SPEEDOFREC=5;

PROC SORT by AID;


PROC FREQ; TABLES SPEEDOFREC*RACE/CHISQ;
```

So for intance I want toe SPEEDOFREC=1 to Say "Very Fast" and 2 to say "Fast".  And then for Race=1 to say "More than 1 race" and 2 to say "Hispanic".  See picture below that I want to change.  Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Just search online for `proc format` and your solution will be very clear